# Getting info from a google play store comment with python

Tags: python, google-play

I've found a bug on a application and now i want to fix it, send it to developers.

The app said that if you put your reference code from the app to their comments on google play store, they would give you 5 coins. I put my reference code using multiple accounts and it worked. I got lots of coins.
I learned that they were giving coins by hands, without an algorithm.
So i want to get the "140678" "127568" like reference codes from comments.

I know python so i would appreciate python codes.

Comment: what have you tried? StackOverflow will help you to solve "problems", what problems have you faced while achieving your goal?

Comment: I'am currently trying Google reviews API